# Is there a way to show loading indicator on Android app resume?

Tags: android, android-activity, resume

Is there a way to control what's shown on the screen when an `Android` app is restarted after it has been stopped? By stopped I mean the apps has been sent to background and at some point the OS reclaimed the resources.
Now when I select the app from the task switching view it shows the `ActionBar` and black background (the background in fact has been set transparent to reduce overdraw) and after a couple of seconds it resumes the activity.
Would it be possible to show some sort of loading indicator (e.g. a `ProgressBar`) instead of just black background?

Comment: Post the code, where the background has been set to transparent.

Comment: For those kinds of screens, you can take a look at this tutorial here- > http://www.41post.com/4588/programming/android-coding-a-loading-screen-part-1 or use a splash screen -> http://www.androidpeople.com/android-loading-welcome-splash-spash-screen-example

Comment: The window background is set in the `onCreate` method of the `Activity` that's being "restarted".  
  
`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
setContentView(R.layout.lite_side_navigation);  
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);  
`
  
After that code a viewpager with three fragments is being initialized and that's it.

Comment: Check the tutorial for the Loading screen if that's what you want implemented.